# Decrease a borders length

Tags: html, css, border

I am currently trying to design the right border. However I want to make the border smaller. I know that it is padding in the CSS that is making it bigger but i need the padding for an another function. Is this even possible without covering a part of the border with an another element?

```css
.sort-search { /* filter padding */
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  color: black;
  background: none;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Telefon" id="sort-search1" class="sort-search">
<input type="button" value="Namn" id="sort-search2" class="sort-search">
<input type="button" value="Kompetens" id="sort-search3" class="sort-search">
<input type="button" value="Orginasation" id="sort-search4" class="sort-search">
<input type="button" value="Roll" id="sort-search5" class="sort-search">
```

[image]

Comment: I've edited your question to make it a snippet.  Much easier to get help that way.  Now, what exactly are you trying to do? Do you mean to make the space smaller between the element and the border?  can you use javascript?  Why do you need the padding for another function?

Comment: Since its a button, you technically don't even need a `border right` unless you are trying to customize it other than `border-right: 1px solid black`. Buttons come with borders.To get what you want you might have to get rid of `padding-bottom`.

Comment: Ah sry if I was a bit unclear. I think that the one of the answears might have solved my problems but I haven't checked. I made a skecth example for others to understand.  @DCR

Answer (score 4):

If you can wrap your `inputs` inside a div, you could use pseudolement `:after` to make the border as you want. (you can't use `:after` on an input)

```css
.sort-search { /* filter padding */
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  background: none;  
  outline: none;
}
div {
  position:relative; 
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  }
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color:black;
  height: 12px; /*THE HEIGHT YOU WANT FOR YOUR LINE*/
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
}
```

```html
<div><input type="button" value="Telefon" id="sort-search1" class="sort-search"></div>
<div><input type="button" value="Namn" id="sort-search2" class="sort-search"></div>
<div><input type="button" value="Kompetens" id="sort-search3" class="sort-search"></div>
<div><input type="button" value="Orginasation" id="sort-search4" class="sort-search"></div>
<div><input type="button" value="Roll" id="sort-search5" class="sort-search"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

replace padding-bottom with margin-bottom.

```css
.sort-search { /* filter padding */
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  color: black;
  background: none;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 0%;
  margin-bottom:4%;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Telefon" id="sort-search1" class="sort-search">
<input type="button" value="Namn" id="sort-search2" class="sort-search">
<input type="button" value="Kompetens" id="sort-search3" class="sort-search">
<input type="button" value="Orginasation" id="sort-search4" class="sort-search">
<input type="button" value="Roll" id="sort-search5" class="sort-search">
```

Comment: Decrease the length of border with the original padding.

Comment: can you draw a picture for what you want to see?